# Span vertical line through page with minipage

Tags: minipage, rules

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, showframe]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\section*{Notation}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\subsection*{Part 1}
\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{5.5ex}p{34.5ex}}
$\textrm{PV}$       &   present value\\
$\textrm{FV}_{N}$   &   future value\\
$r$                 &   interest rate\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\vline\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\subsection*{Part 2}
\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{5.5ex}p{34.5ex}}
$\mu$               &   mean\\
$\sigma$            &   standard deviation\\
$\sigma^2$          &   variance\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

which produces this output:

[image]

Is it possible with my current setup to make the vertical line span the entire page (this page only), while still being in the center as shown? I have read multiple questions on the same topic on the site, but I weren't able to find one matching my specific issue, sorry if I missed any. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "span the 'entire' page"?

Comment: @MarianG. That the vertical line that separates the two parts is about the same length as the paper/page instead of just a few centimeters as shown in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\twocolumn`. Issue `\onecolumn` at the end if you have further pages.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\doublespacing

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[\section*{Notation}]

\subsection*{Part 1}
\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{5.5ex}p{34.5ex}}
$\textrm{PV}$       &   present value\\
$\textrm{FV}_{N}$   &   future value\\
$r$                 &   interest rate\\
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak

\subsection*{Part 2}
\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{5.5ex}p{34.5ex}}
$\mu$               &   mean\\
$\sigma$            &   standard deviation\\
$\sigma^2$          &   variance\\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]